# Couchbase unable to retrieve document No index available Code 4000

Tags: couchbase

I have a bucket in Couchbase called `mybucket`. When I select Documents and then choose my bucket, It has an option to retrieve the documents. When I choose the first one, the web platform of Couchbase shows the content of that document to me:

```json
{
  "type": "activity",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  ....
}
```

So, with that, I am sure that I can see some documents that have `"type" = "activity"` in my bucket. However, when I want to retrieve them using the Query editor and the following N1QL query:

```sql
select * from `mybucket` where `type` = "activity" limit 10;
```

I get the following response:

```json
[
  {
    "code": 4000,
    "msg": "No index available on keyspace `default`:`mybucket` that matches your query. Use CREATE PRIMARY INDEX ON `default`:`mybucket` to create a primary index, or check that your expected index is online.",
    "query": "select * from `mybucket` where `type` = \"activity\" limit 10;"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bucket Retrieve documents uses DCP stream vs Query Editor uses N1QL which required the secondary index or primary index

Option 1) CREATE INDEX ix1 ON mybuckte(type);

OR

Option 2) CREATE PRIMARY INDEX on mybucket;